# Error posting data with android

Tags: java, php, android, sql, post

I am having an error that I can't seem to figure out why.  I am  trying to post data to a php file and am falling into a catch error.  The toast I am getting in my catch is "Data was not sent", but I am getting the "Data was prepared" toast right before it.  Could anybody take a look and help me identify what my problem is?

The android method:

```
public void insertToDB(String data){
        try {
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost getMethod=new HttpPost("http://shawnc.webuda.com/upload.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RPM",data));
            getMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            String toastText = "Data was prepared";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                client.execute(getMethod);
                toastText = "Data has been sent: " + data;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                toastText = "Data was not sent";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            String toastText = "Data could not be prepared";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and my php file:

```
<?
$hostname_host ="MYSQLxxxxx.Smarterasp.net";
$database_host ="db_xxxxx_db";
$username_host ="9xxxxx_db";
$password_host ="password";

$server= mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db("db_xxxxx_db");
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO driverdata (RPM)VALUES('".$_REQUEST['RPM']."')");

$r=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$r)
echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Check the error message in the Exception. Most likely that will contain beneficial information that should help you solve it. It may be a network issue, server config, who knows. Look at the exception. What is the stack trace and message in the exception?

Comment: How can i see the stacktrace.  I am running it from my phone because it connects to an obdII sensor in my car so I can't use an emulator?

Comment: It could be this line `$server= mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);` - It probably needs an `if/else` - Try `if($server= mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost))
else {trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);}` - See http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php for a few more examples.

Comment: Plus `mysql_select_db("db_xxxxx_db");` may need DB variable passed to it `mysql_select_db("db_xxxxx_db",$server);`

Comment: Wouldn't the app at least work fine if the data got sent to the php file.  Or would it also fail the app because the sql could not be inserted properly?

Comment: That I couldn't say. I don't know anything about Android, just PHP/SQL. What's the exact error message you're getting? Is an Android based error or SQL/PHP?

Comment: Android based, its falling into that catch when it is trying to send the data on the client.execute.  This tells me that it is not making it to the php file and no data is being inserted.  Must be something with that execute.

Comment: can you post the stack trace here.

Comment: I wish I knew how.  I have to run it from my phone because it connects to my car, so I don't use the emulator.  Do you know of a way to do that from the phone?

Comment: In the toast - you want to toast the exception message.  You could also have it write debug info to a file or open an intent to send an email to yourself.

But I think it's clear - this is not a PHP issue.  It's a problem with the client.execute(getMethod) call.  Haven't done anything in Android in a while so I can't help out much.

Comment: Check the url you are using is proper and the data you are sending, the key and format of your data. Exceptions mostly occur if these are not in correct format as expected.

Comment: please add e.printStackTrace in catch block to see error msg

Answer (score 1):

When you do not know where is problem try replace PHP script by

```
<?php
echo "OK";
?>
```

and try read response from PHP

```
try {
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod);
     toastText = "Data has been sent: " + data;
```

When you get response OK problem is in PHP.

When i use httppost i use this code to get response. When i have response http request is OK.

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 2000);
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpParameters.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx.com/upload.php");
        request.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 5000);

        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RPM",data));              

        try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        //do with response
```